# In a Class call an element HTML in a method for an addEventlistener in an other method

Tags: javascript, class, methods, addeventlistener

(i'm french, i going to try to explain in english but if you can't understand i'm sorry).
I had looking on MDN and i had tried to find the answer here but i think i don't use the good keywords.

So, i'm learning JS, and i have a exercice to do for my first classes (\o/). But I'm blocked step 3.

I need to add in my classe a method (changeStatut) with a addEventListener on a "click" of a button create whith an other method (addToDOM()) of this class . And i don't understand how to indicate THIS.

Do i need to use a "this" in the second method ? but how ?

this button "on click" need to change sur value of my bolean "done".

```
class Task {
    title;
    priority;
    done=false;

    constructor(title,priority){
        this.title=title;
        this.priority=priority;
    }

    addToDOM(){
    const tasklist = document.getElementById("tasks");
    const newTask = document.createElement("li");
    newTask.classList.add("task-item");

    const taskTitle = document.createElement("span");
    taskTitle.classList.add("task-title");
    taskTitle.textContent = `${this.title}`;

    const taskPriority = document.createElement("span");
    taskPriority.classList.add("task-priority");
    taskPriority.textContent = `${this.priority}`;
    taskPriority.classList.add(`task-priority--${this.priority}`);

    const taskButton = document.createElement("button");
    taskButton.classList.add("task-action");
    taskButton.textContent = "Changer le statut";

    tasklist.prepend(newTask);
    newTask.append(taskTitle,taskPriority,taskButton);

    }

    changeStatut(){

         let statut = this.done;
             statut = !statut;
             return statut;
        }

    }   

const task2 = new Task("Tailler la haie",3);
task2.addToDOM();
```

i had try to point on the same ID of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your are looking for something like that ?

```
class Task
  {
  _tasklist = document.getElementById('tasks')
    ;
  constructor(title, priority) 
    {
    this.title    = title;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.done     = false;
    }
  addToDOM()
    {
    const
      newTask      = this._tasklist.appendChild( document.createElement('li') )
    , taskTitle    = newTask.appendChild( document.createElement('span'))
    , taskPriority = newTask.appendChild( document.createElement('span'))
    , taskButton   = newTask.appendChild( document.createElement('button'))
      ;
    newTask     .className = 'task-item';
    taskTitle   .className = 'task-title';
    taskPriority.className = `task-priority task-priority--${this.priority}`;
    taskButton  .className = 'task-action';    
    
    taskTitle   .textContent = this.title;
    taskPriority.textContent = this.priority;
    taskButton  .textContent = 'Changer le statut';

    taskButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>
      {
      this.done = !this.done;
      console.log( 'this.done :' , this.done )
      return this.done;
      });
  } }
  
const task2 = new Task('Tailler la haie', 3);
task2.addToDOM();
```

following **Peter Seliger**'s comment:

> What is the reason for using a pseudo private `_tasklist` instead of the available true private `#tasklist` ?

I realized that I had missed this good evolution of language.
so here is a fix:

```js
class Task
  {
  static #tasklist = document.getElementById('tasks')
    ;
  constructor(title, priority) 
    {
    let fragHTML = new Range().createContextualFragment( 
     `<li class="task-item">
        <span class="task-title">${title}</span>
        <span class="task-priority task-priority--${priority}">${priority}</span>
        <span>...</span>
        <button class="task-action">Changer le statut</button>
      </li>`);
    this.done       = false;
    this.statut_elm = fragHTML.querySelector('li > span:nth-of-type(3)');

    fragHTML.querySelector('button.task-action').addEventListener('click', () =>
      {
      this.done                   = !this.done;
      this.statut_elm.textContent = this.done ? 'done' : '...';
      });
    
    Task.#tasklist.prepend(fragHTML);
  } }

const
  task2 = new Task('Tailler la haie', 3)
, taskZ = new Task('éplucher les carottes', 15)
  ;
```

```css
#tasks { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; }
#tasks li { width: 30em; height: 1.8em; margin: .2em 0; }
#tasks li span { display: inline-block; padding: 0.4em .5em 0 .5em; }
#tasks li span:first-of-type { width: 12em; } 
#tasks li span:nth-of-type(2) { width: 2em; text-align: right; } 
#tasks li button { float: right; }
```

```html
<ul id="tasks"></ul>
```

Comment: thanks. I was that easy ... I hate JS ...

(i lied, i love JS x))

Comment: @MisterJojo ... What is the reason for using a pseudo private `_tasklist` instead of the available true private  `#tasklist`?

Comment: @PeterSeliger You're right ! I missed this evolution of language. I added this update to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about some true [privacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_properties) and a maybe better readable/maintainable implementation ...

```js
function parseElementNode(markup) {
  return (new DOMParser)
    .parseFromString(markup, 'text/html')
    .body
    .firstElementChild;
}

class Task {
  #parentRoot;
  #elmRoot;

  constructor(parentSelector, title, priority) {
    this.#parentRoot = document.querySelector(parentSelector);

    Object.assign(this, { title, priority, done: false });
  }
 
  mount() {  
    const markup = `
      <li class="task-item">
        <span class="task-title">${ this.title }</span>
        <span class="task-priority task-priority--${ this.priority }">
          ${ this.priority }
        </span>
        <span class="task-done"></span>
        <button class="task-action">${ 'Changer le statut' }</button>
      </li>`;

    this.#elmRoot = parseElementNode(markup);
    this.renderDone();

    this.#elmRoot.querySelector('button')
      .addEventListener('click', () => {

        this.done = !this.done;
        this.renderDone();
      });
    this.#parentRoot.prepend(this.#elmRoot);
  }

  renderDone() {
    console.log(this);

    this.#elmRoot.querySelector('.task-done')
      .textContent = (this.done && 'done' || '... ...');
  }
}

const task1 = new Task('#tasks', 'Arroser les fleurs', 2);
const task2 = new Task('#tasks', 'Tailler la haie', 3);

task2.mount();
task1.mount();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tasks"></ul>
```